# Using CascadeType in Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring

I m working with Hibernate + Spring and JSF

I have a problem when I use a relationship  like @OneTomany in Hibernate. For example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "book")
public class Book {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String description;
    private String image;
    private int numberOfPages;
    private Date releaseDate;
    private String title;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "category_id")
    private Category category;
```

When I remove CascadeType.ALL and save a book containing a category, the Id of Category becomes null.

Can anyone help me to resolve this problem?

**Edit:** This is my unit test that causes the error when I remve CascadeType.ALL

```
BookDao bookDao = (BookDao) applicationContext.getBean("bookDao");
Category category = new Category();
category.setTitle("Title");
Book book = new Book();
book.setCategory(category);
bookDao.save(book);
long id = book.getCategory().getId();
assertTrue(id > 0);
```

Comment: Is it the category the book contains one that's already in the database?

Comment: this is my unit testthat cause the error when i remve cascadeType.ALL                                                          BookDao bookDao = (BookDao) applicationContext.getBean("bookDao");
  Category category = new Category();
  category.setTitle("Title");
  Book book = new Book();
  book.setCategory(category);
  bookDao.save(book);
  long id = book.getCategory().getId();
  assertTrue(id > 0);

Comment: You should post additional code by editing your question instead of putting it in a comment. I've taken the liberty of putting it in the question for you. You can delete this comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at ["Cascading life cycle"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/example-parentchild.html#example-parentchild-cascades) to understand how cascading works. Unless you're assigning ids manually, an entity only gets an id assigned [when it's saved](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#save%28java.lang.Object%29). If you're cascading saves from Book to Category, then saving the Book also saves the Category. Without cascading, the Category doesn't get saved, and therefore it has no id.